# Atmega32 can't verify after setting correct fuses for external crystal. HELP

Tags: atmega, clock, atmel, crystal, fuses

I am having trouble with some Atmega32A's purchased off from eBay. The MCU's does not seem to be fake as they are functioning properly. I am experiencig the following problem: I want to use external crystal of 14.7456MHz. With default fuse settings (

```
0xE1 / 0b11100001 low fuse;
0x99 / 0b10011001 high fuse;
```

) I am able to program the MCU and it verifies, everything is OK when it works with internal clock speed at 1MHz. When I change high fuse to 0b11001001 to disable JTAG and program CKOPT, it works again. But when I change low fuse to make the MCU to use external clock, it writes the hex, but cannot verify the MCU, and it's not working. Here's the output:

```
> "make.exe" program
avrdude -p atmega32 -P usb -c usbasp    -U flash:w:main.hex 

avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e9502
avrdude: NOTE: FLASH memory has been specified, an erase cycle will be performed
         To disable this feature, specify the -D option.
avrdude: erasing chip
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: reading input file "main.hex"
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: writing flash (15896 bytes):

Writing | ################################################## | 100% 6.73s

avrdude: 15896 bytes of flash written
avrdude: verifying flash memory against main.hex:
avrdude: load data flash data from input file main.hex:
avrdude: input file main.hex auto detected as Intel Hex
avrdude: input file main.hex contains 15896 bytes
avrdude: reading on-chip flash data:

Reading | ################################################## | 100% 4.87s

avrdude: verifying ...
avrdude: verification error, first mismatch at byte 0x0000
         0x0c != 0x00
avrdude: verification error; content mismatch

avrdude done.  Thank you.

make.exe: *** [program] Error 1

> Process Exit Code: 2
> Time Taken: 00:12
```

The programmer is working fine, I can confirm the circuit is working because it's working with Atmega32 when setting to use external clock (I am using 2x22pF ceramic capacitors right next to the crystal). The issue is with these Atmega32A's. What can be the reason? I found this, but I think 1111 is the correct one for the crystal.

```
Device clocking options             CKSEL 3..0
External crystal/ceramic resonator  1111-1010
External low frequency crystal      1001
External RC oscillator              1000-0101
Calibrated Internal RC oscillator   0100-0001
External clock                      0000
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whats your supply voltage? Is it sufficient for 14MHz?

Comment: it's 5V from the USB port of the computer. The issue does not seem to be the voltage, because this error happens while programming the MCU.

Comment: Could you edit your question to explicitly say: "When I use exactly the same 'blink' program and exactly the same fuse settings and exactly the same programmer and exactly the same crystal+capacitors, my ATmega32 seems to program and then blink an LED fine, but my ATmega32A can't be verified and doesn't blink the LED. However, both of them verify and blink fine when I use the 'internal clock' fuse setting" (Is that right?). Thanks.

Comment: According to people on the internet [a](http://www.edaboard.com/thread259430.html) [b](http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=816210) [c](http://www.instructables.com/answers/ATMEGA32-vs-ATMEGA32A-PU/) and Atmel's "AVR521: Migrating from ATmega32 to 
ATmega32A"[(d)](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8162.pdf), the ATmega32A should be a drop-in replacement for the ATmega32. Software (including the programming/verification tools) shouldn't even be able to tell the difference.